# Interior of a solid self dual cone

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a real Hilbert space with a solid self dual positive cone $K$, that is, $\mathrm{int}(K)$ is non-empty and $K^{*}=K$. If $X$ is finite dimensional, I know that the $\mathrm{int}(K)$ =  $\left\{x\in X  | \langle x, y \rangle > 0  \mbox{ for all }  y\in K\setminus\{0\}\right\}.$ But I am not sure whether it is true for infinite dimensional space. Can anyone please clarify it!

Comment: Do you have an example for an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space with a solid self-dual cone?

Comment: Please see this link for an example:https://books.google.co.in/books?id=kTFDAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=example+of+an+infinite+dimensional+solid+self-dual+cone&source=bl&ots=us-t_T574U&sig=hIBhMFwQgUgO3-wj8j01dAVvhPQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiysZDN6PDNAhWMOY8KHejtCFMQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=example%20of%20an%20infinite%20dimensional%20solid%20self-dual%20cone&f=false